# mysql JSON_ARRAYAGG or GROUP_CONCAT with limit

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

Is there a way in mysql8.0 to do a limit within `JSON_ARRAYAGG` or `GROUP_CONCAT`? For example:

```
WITH season AS (
    select 'DAL'  as team, 4 as wins, 2000 as season UNION
    select 'DAL'  as team, 10 as wins, 2001 as season UNION
    select 'DAL'  as team, 9 as wins, 2002 as season UNION
    select 'GB'  as team, 2 as wins, 2000 as season UNION
    select 'GB'  as team, 3 as wins, 2001 as season UNION
    select 'GB'  as team, 4 as wins, 2002 as season
) SELECT
    team,
    GROUP_CONCAT(wins order by season desc separator '+') wins_str,
    JSON_ARRAYAGG(wins) wins_arr
FROM season
GROUP BY team;
```

For example, how would I only get the first 5 `wins` in the above two fields? For example I'm looking to do something like you can do within BigQuery [`STRING_AGG`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#string_agg), where it accepts a `LIMIT`.

Comment: Please add some sample data and desired output

Comment: @AkhileshMishra see updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest method is window functions:

```
SELECT
    team,
    GROUP_CONCAT(wins ORDER BY season DESC SEPARATOR '+') wins,
    JSON_ARRAYAGG(wins)
FROM (
    SELECT s.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY team ORDER BY seasons DESC
    ) AS seqnum
    FROM seasons s
) s
WHERE seqnum <= 5
GROUP BY team
```

Comment: I think with the `json_arrayagg` it supports an `OVER` within the syntax? `JSON_ARRAYAGG(col_or_expr) [over_clause]`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg